# how to snapshot multiple query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform multiple where query but it's not working. Can someone tell me how to write the following in the correct way

```
useEffect(()=> {
  db.collection("posts")
    .where("username", "==", currentUser.email)
    .where("draft", "==", true)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
         setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.data()))
      })
}, [])
```

Comment: it would be better do shapsht not in useEffect but in module with firebase instance

Comment: still not fetching data

Comment: did you fetch it without `where` conditions?

Comment: thankyou it's working